# How can I make a math version of itemize, enumerate, and description environments?

Tags: math-mode, lists

`tabular` is to `array` as `itemize` is to …?

I'd like to have a list like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqlist}
\item E=mc^2
\item e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{eqlist}
\end{document}
```

I'm already using `enumitem`, but I don't *think* that package will be of any help.  Of course, any solution will work :)

Important variations:

- What about display math?
- What about the other `list` environments – like `description` and `enumerate`?

## Use Case

The use-case is pretty trivial, actually – to have a list of equations.  You could call this 'for fun', but I have in the past actually hacked something together for class notes that allowed me to do something like this (e.g. listing out and naming the properties of algebraic groups).  I had thought the idea was limited to that so I never generalized my (terribly messy) solution, but I'm seeing the pattern pop-up more and more in various documents where it actually *doesn't* look absolutely awful as you'd expect. Conveniently, I don't have any solid examples except [this newbie document that popped up on reddit.com/r/LaTeX](http://redd.it/3ez19r).

Comment: Since there is no math *declaration*, you'll have to capture the `\item`s and process them.

Comment: There's no correspondent; use `gather` or `align`. Why would you need bullets or similar things?

Comment: do, please, add to the question your reason for wanting to do this.  perhaps a multiple choice situation?

Comment: @barbarabeeton See edit (and thanks for your spelling correction :) it was a late night).

Comment: That GIF made my day! `<3`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution (it doesn't use, but I hope it will be compatible with `enumitem`)

**Note:** I don't understand what the OP want to do with display math

**Limitation:** blank lines  not supported (this code will not work)

```
\begin{mathitem}
\item E=mc^2

\item e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{mathitem}
```

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{amsmath,url}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mtmathitem}{%
\xpatchcmd{\item}{\@inmatherr\item}{\relax\ifmmode$\fi}{}{\errmessage{Patching of \noexpand\item failed}}
\xapptocmd{\@item}{$}{}{\errmessage{appending to \noexpand\@item failed}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{mathitem}[1][]{%
\itemize[#1]\mtmathitem}{$\endlist}                    %$

\newenvironment{mathenum}[1][]{%
\enumerate[#1]\mtmathitem}{$\endlist}                  %$

\newenvironment{mathdesc}[1][]{%
\description[#1]\mtmathitem}{$\endlist}                %$


\begin{document}

\begin{mathitem}
\item E=mc^2
\item e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{mathitem}


\begin{mathenum}
\item E=mc^2
\item e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{mathenum}


\begin{mathenum}[label=\emph{\alph*})]
\item E=mc^2
\item e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{mathenum}

\begin{mathdesc}
\item[some] E=mc^2
\item[thing] e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item[else] \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{mathdesc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1). Does it work with the amsmath environments? I mean could we have, say, an align environment, with the bullet aligned with the first line of the environment, while keeping equation tags on the right side?

Comment: @Bernard I didn't try. As I noted in the answer I don't understand what the OP want do with displaymath.

Comment: The displaymath isn't rightly my idea – I was originally content to just center (`\hfil content\hfil`) the content. The document I wrote this question for (see edit) does use display-style mathematics, though. Whether I agree with the layout isn't really of consequence at the end of the day. It's not 'optimal', but it's also not *terrible* – the best thing to do would be do re-imagine how the information is presented, but that's not feasible in this situation. (Of course I imagine it would be unproblematic to insert a `\displaystyle`, but this doesn't help the centering.)

Answer (score 5):

(Answer modified to (i) add a "MathDescription" environment and (ii) demonstrate compatibility with the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.)

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It defines three new environments called `MathItemize`, `MathEnumerate`, and `MathDescription`. The environments work just like the "ordinary" `itemize`, `enumerate`, and `description` environments, except that all material (other than the descriptive labels in the `MathDescription` environment) is typeset in math mode instead of text mode.

If need be, `\displaystyle` can be inserted after `\item` in order to render an item's contents in displaymath mode. Use

```
\item \displaystyle \hfill <formula> \hfill
```

to center-set the display-math material.

The code appears to work very well with the `enumitem` package. To wit, the example below below loads the `enumitem` package and changes some of the default settings of the `itemize` and `enumerate` environments.

As the OP's write-up and comments do not seem to indicate a need for nested lists, the code works only for non-nested lists.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for "\text" macro
\usepackage{url,hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

%% Check compatibility with "enumitem" package...
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{itemsep=1ex}
\setlist[itemize]{label=$\star$}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\roman*), leftmargin=*, widest = iii}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}
%% Lua-side code: Three Boolean variables, two new
%% functions, & calls to assign the new functions to 
%% the "process_input_buffer" callback
\begin{luacode}
env_type_1 = false
env_type_2 = false
first_list_item = true

function change_item_properties_itemenum ( line )
  if (env_type_1 == true) then
    if (first_list_item == true) then
        line = string.gsub( line, "\\item", "\\item $" )
        first_list_item = false
    else 
        line = string.gsub( line, "\\item", "$ \\item $" )
    end  
  end  
  return (line)
end

function change_item_properties_desc ( line )
  if (env_type_2 == true) then
    if (first_list_item == true) then
        line = string.gsub( line, "(\\item.-%[.-%])", "%0 $" )
        first_list_item = false
    else 
        line = string.gsub( line, "(\\item.-%[.-%])", "$ %0 $" )
    end  
  end  
  return (line)
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer",
        change_item_properties_itemenum, 
        "MathModeItemizeEnumerate" )
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer",
        change_item_properties_desc, 
        "MathModeDescription" )
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code -- Three new environments: 
%% MathItemize, MathEnumerate, MathDescription
\newenvironment{MathItemize}%
  {\directlua{ env_type_1 = true }
   \begin{itemize} }%
  {$\end{itemize}
   \directlua{ env_type_1 = false 
               first_list_item = true}}
\newenvironment{MathEnumerate}%
  {\directlua{ env_type_1 = true }
   \begin{enumerate}}%
  {$\end{enumerate}
   \directlua{ env_type_1 = false 
               first_list_item = true}}
\newenvironment{MathDescription}%
  {\directlua{ env_type_2 = true }
   \begin{description}}%
  {$\end{description}
   \directlua{ env_type_2 = false 
               first_list_item = true}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
A \verb+MathItemize+ list
\begin{MathItemize}
\item E=mc^2
\item e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item \text{ducks} + \text{caffeine}
    = \text{\url{https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVksc.gif}}
\end{MathItemize}

\bigskip\noindent
An ``ordinary'' \verb+itemize+ list
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello world.
\item Goodbye world.
\end{itemize}

\bigskip\noindent
A \verb+MathEnumerate+ list
\begin{MathEnumerate}
\item a^2+b^2=c^2
\item \displaystyle \hfill \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \hfill
\item 1+1=2
\end{MathEnumerate}

\bigskip\noindent
A \verb+MathDescription+ list
\begin{MathDescription}
\item [Einstein] \hfill  E=mc^2 \hfill 
\item[Euler] e^{i\pi}+1=0
\item  [Pythagoras] a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{MathDescription}

\bigskip\noindent
Finally, an ``ordinary'' \verb+enumerate+ list
\begin{enumerate}[widest=ii] 
\item abcdef, and
\item uvwxyz.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@mathitemize
\newif\if@closemathitem
\let\orig@item=\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\if@closemathitem$\fi\orig@item\if@mathitemize\@closemathitemtrue$\fi}
\newenvironment{mathitemize}{\@mathitemizetrue\itemize\@closemathitemfalse}{$\enditemize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test2
\end{itemize}

\begin{mathitemize}
\item E=mc^2
\end{mathitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need `ifthen` here?

Comment: Actually no.. Thanks. I'll change the post accordingly.

Comment: this does not work for more than one item

Comment: I was about to make the same remark as @touhami; moreover, `\@mathitemizefalse` at the end of the environment is redundant (a group is about to end).

Comment: My bad. I'll post an updated version in a short moment. Thanks for the remarks.

Comment: Updated version works for longer lists. However (because it is quick and dirty), it will not support nested lists.