# Placing vertical lines between columns

Tags: minipage, multicol

I have a document that looks like this

[image]

The horizontal line is just a `\hrule`, but the two vertical lines are made with a textblock. Is there an easier way to place them?

Using a table environment is not an option, since the vertical space between items goes bananas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=0.8in,left=0.8in,right=0.8in,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{10mm}{10mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{textblock}{3}(6.3,0.75)%%%Places a vertical line
\rule{0.1mm}{18cm}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{3}(15,0.75)%%%Places a vertical line
\rule{0.1mm}{18cm}
\end{textblock}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
\centering{FUS} 
\end{tabularx}
\hrule

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}{0.44\textwidth}
\vspace{15cm}   
RO
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.44\textwidth}
DAH
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Easier... easier how? Why is what you have "difficult"? What else do you want to do with the output?

Comment: @Werner
I have to tell LaTeX where and how long I want that line. It has to be adjusted every time the `\hrule` moves, or the columns width changes. 

Tinkering like that is what I'd expect on a WYSIWYG, not on LaTeX.

Comment: @Kurzd you could create your own environment, and automatize all those lengths based on the characteristics of the content, using `savebox`. Or you could try more elaborated table environments. Check this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Columns_spanning_multiple_rows

Comment: Or not use a table at all, but rather something like `multicol`. @Werner I'm pretty sure OP is talking about the apparent 'hackiness' of the doc. I'm not really sure how much we can infer (since the given solution 'works' but is suboptimal for varying definitions of 'optimal'). OP, what is your *goal* for this document, what have you tried to work towards that goal, and what is the hang-up with that approach? (Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258199/17423 because I'm cheating a little. OP's document is a maths reference sheet.)

Comment: I'm trying to make one of [these](http://i.imgur.com/xKfDzsJ.jpg). There's four of those, all of them with different layouts and glaring mistakes.

Comment: I'm trying to make a single template to make them all. @phollox's savebox suggestion is both scary and appropriate. 

That document went from a *single* `tabularx` to a multicolumn, 4 `tabularx` doc.

@SeanAllred it's somewhat annoying having to move those lines around everytime something in the layout changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives a similar output. Is it 'easier'?

The height of the vertical rules is calculated automatically using `\pagegoal` (total vertical space available within margins) and `\pagetotal` (amount of vertical space already used on current page).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[top=1.3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\centering
FUS
\hrule{}

\newlength\minipageheight
\setlength\minipageheight{\pagegoal-\pagetotal-1mm}

\begin{minipage}[t][\minipageheight][t]{0.33\textwidth}
\vfill
RO
\end{minipage}%
\vrule{}
\begin{minipage}[t][\minipageheight][t]{0.33\textwidth}
\smallskip
\centering
DAH
\end{minipage}%
\vrule{}
\begin{minipage}[t][\minipageheight][t]{0.33\textwidth}
\smallskip
\centering
JOOR
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion made all the columns jump to a second page, leaving that `FUS` alone. I changed `\minipageheight`'s definition to 16 cm, and they're all now on the same page.

Comment: I think this is because of rounding errors from the calculation of `\minipageheight`. `0.99\minipageheight` fits on one page for me, but `1.01\minipageheight` does not. I have updated the solution, and made `\minipageheight` shorter by 1mm.