# How to add a vertical ruler between columns for tikzposter?

Tags: tikzposter

How can I add a vertical ruler between `columns` for `tikzposter` document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95169/how-to-separate-beamer-columns-with-vertical-lines, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23887/how-to-show-the-vertical-line-between-two-columns or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258764/placing-vertical-lines-between-columns could be reladed links.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Nope, none of those work in `tikzposter`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any *good* ways of doing this, but since a `tikzposter` is basically just a big `tikzpicture` environment, one can  use normal TikZ drawing commands. In that context it's nice to know that `tikzposter` defines coordinates `bottomleft` and `topright` at the corresponding points on the page, and that the vertical position of the bottom of the title is saved in `\titleposbottom`.

(You probably want to modify how those rules look, but that I'll leave to you.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a2paper]{tikzposter}
\author{Zum Dood}
\title{Line it up}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{columns}
\column{0.33}
\block{A}{Foo bar}

\column{0.33}
\block{A}{Foo bar}

\column{0.33}
\block{A}{Foo bar}

\end{columns}

% draw two red lines
\path (bottomleft) 
      +(0.34\linewidth,1cm) coordinate (c1)
      +(0.66\linewidth,1cm) coordinate (c2); 
\draw [line width=5mm,red] (c1) -- (c1 |- 0,\titleposbottom-1cm);
\draw [line width=5mm,red] (c2) -- (c2 |- 0,\titleposbottom-1cm);

\end{document}
```