# How can I add big curl bracket on the right size with \item

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
 \begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \[ 
 \left.\begin{array}{r}

  \textnormal{a}\\[.5ex]

 \textnormal{b}\\[.5ex]
 \textnormal{c}
 \end{array} \right\} 
\longrightarrow \textnormal{d}
 \]
 \end{itemize}
 \end{document}
```

I want \item in front of a, b and c and right parenthesis for a and b.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258192/how-can-i-make-a-math-version-of-itemize-enumerate-and-description-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question is not very clear, so I guess that you maybe looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    $\left.
    \parbox{0.4\linewidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item   Some content..
\item   Some content..
\item   Some more content..
    \end{enumerate}
    }\right\} \Longrightarrow D$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Your question is still unclear (provided code is not compilable, its structure is quite strange). If, as now follows from your comment below, the main problem you have, is how to define bullets, I wonder why you not use simple `itemize` and than describe where you like to have parenthesis and `\Longrightarrow`. So the here is new guessing about what probably you after:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                    calligraphy,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   a: there is some \tikzmarknode{A}{content}
\item   b: in this item is some longer \tikzmarknode{B}{content}
\item   last item 
    \end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
BC/.style = {decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
        raise=4pt},
        very thick,
        pen colour=red}
                 ]
\path[BC]   (A.north -| B.east) -- node[right=8pt] {$\Longrightarrow d$} (B.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After at least twice compilation (due to use of `overlay,remember picture,` options in tikzpicture), above MWE produce:

[image]

Comment: Yes, i am looking for the same, but how shall i get bullets (\itemize) instead of a)

Comment: Sachin: In LaTeX, itemize environment gives items as bullets by default & only enumerate environment gives numbers as list entries. The above code gives bullets only as item labels and all you have to do is to remove "a:", "b:" and "c:" from it. Thanks!